# Extract value from alert dialog to dynamically update generated EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have created `EditText` views dynamically. I have also created an alert `dialog` with an `EditText` view. Now I should get the text typed in alert dialog box to the dynamically generated `EditText`. Please help me..

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



     EditText input = new EditText(this);
    Context Context = this;
    AlertDialog Alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(Context).setTitle("Add Field").setMessage("Proceed").setView(input).setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }


    }).show();


        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.editTextGroupLayout);
         EditText editTextView = new EditText(this);
        editTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        editTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
        editTextView.setHint("Enter Field ");
        linearLayout.addView(editTextView);


 if(v.getId()==R.id.button_selectoptionsback){




            Intent a=new Intent(this,Admin.class);
            this.startActivity(a);

    }    

}
```

}

Comment: Could you please elaborately explain what your program is doing? By making references to the program tell us what problem you are getting, then we will see.

Comment: Just I had created admin and user pages. In admin registration page, I have created edittext dynamically. Also I have created an alert dialog to confirm whether the admin is ready to add the field or not. The text which entered in edit text of alertdialog, the same should appear in to dynamically generated edit text.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that your dialog doesn't have a reference to the second text input.

You could create the 2nd input before the dialog and define it as `final`, in which case you can use it inside the class. In your positive `onClick`, you can then call:

```
editTextView.setText(input.getText());
```

Overall, it'll look something like this:

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
final EditText editTextView = new EditText(this);
AlertDialog /* codez... */ .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        editTextView.setText(input.getText());

        Toast.makeText(/* ... */);
    }
}) /* more code */
```

Comment: I have created the reference of another edittext under the linear layout. @ David

Answer (score 0):

Your `EditText` is declared after your `Dialog`which is wrong. What you should so is that the `EditText` should be declared before the `Dialog` starts, and when the user clicks on the "Yes" button, ie the PositiveResponse, you should add the following code:

```
editTextView.setText(input.getText());
```

This should do the trick.